# How to get SAML token from ADFS in a silveright application using windows credentials

Tags: c#, silverlight, saml, adfs

I am trying acheive active federation with silverlight application.
I would like to request for SAML token from ADFS from my silverlight application.
I cannot use WSTrustChannel in the silverlight app, since it does not allow to add System.IdentityModel or Microsoft.IdentityModel.
Please help.